# nginx webpy fastcgi caching can not work

Tags: caching, nginx, fastcgi, web.py

nginx.conf file content as follow:

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

# configure cache log
log_format cache '$remote_addr - $host [$time_local]  '
             '"$request" $status $upstream_cache_status $body_bytes_sent '
             '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

fastcgi_cache_path  /data0/nginx-cache  levels=1:2
                   keys_zone=nginx_fastcgi_cache:1m
                   inactive=1d;

                   fastcgi_temp_path /data0/nginx-cache/temp;

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  outofmemory.cn localhost;

    access_log /data0/nginx-1.2.6/logs/cache.log cache;

    #charset koi8-r;


    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache   nginx_fastcgi_cache;
    fastcgi_cache_min_uses  1;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error  timeout invalid_header http_500;
    #add_header X-Cache cached;

    fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;

    location / {
      root /www/outofmemory.cn;
      fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
      fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
      fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
      fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
      fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
      fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
      fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
      fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
      fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;

      fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
      fastcgi_cache   nginx_fastcgi_cache;
      fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
    }

    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this question.

I wrote an artile to explain how to configure nginx + webpy + fastcgi cache.

http://outofmemory.cn/code-snippet/2154/nginx-webpy-fastcgi-cache-configuration-explain-in-detail

thanks.

Comment: Not everyone knows Chinese , and I'd appreciate if you could write here in English, too, in case your site goes down.

Answer (score 3):

I also having the same problem. As yukaizhao mentioned in his post, need to added below to ignore expires header or else fastcgi_cache won't work.

```
fastcgi_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires" "Set-Cookie";
```

Thanks yukaizhao!

Comment: I don't really understand this setting, but it worked for me after it stopped working for a while. How does this work? The docs say "Disables processing of certain response header fields from the FastCGI server.", does that mean it just strips out these headers or allows? I don't get it.